# accessing WordPress DB from remote server

Tags: wordpress, server, remote-access, wordpress-rest-api

Need some advice before starting develop some things.. I've 15 WordPress websites on different installs, and I've remote server which gets data 24/7 from those websites.

I've reached a point that I want the server to modify the websites based on his calculated data.

The things are this:

- Should I allow the server the access the WP DB remotely and modify things without using WP on the circle?
- Or, use WP REST API and supply some secured routes which provide data and accept data and make those changes?

My instinct is to use the WP API, but. After all its a PHP (nginx+apache) which have some limits (timeout for example) and I find it hard to run hard and long process on the WP itself.

I can divide the tasks to different levels, for example:

1. fetching data (simple get)
2. make some process on the remote server
3. loop and modify in small batches to another route

My concerns are that this circle require perfect match between remote server and WP API, and any change or fix on WP side brings plugins update on the websites which is not much fun.

Hope for any ideas and suggests to make it forward.

Answer (score 0):

"use WP REST API and supply some secured routes which provide data and accept data and make those changes", indeed.

i don't know why timeout or another limits may cause a problem - but using API is the best way for such kind of cases. You can avoid timeout problems with some adjustments on web servers side.

Or you can increase memory, timeout limit exclusively for requested server.
f.e.

```
if ($_SERVER["remote_attr"]=='YOUR_MAIN_SERVER_IP') {
ini_set('max_execution_time',1000);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
}
```